# Criando Tabela/BD com Django?

Tags: sql, python, django

Uso o python 3.4 e a última versão do django, estou usando o comando "python manage.py sqall" mas não reconhece o comando sqall.(estou tentando criar uma Tabela no Bd, e já inserir os dados corretamente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel para que sua tabela seja criada é necessário que seu app esteja devidamente mapeado dentro de seu arquivo **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'exemplo'
```

]

Para que a migração seja feita de forma correta utiliza-se o comando `python manage.py makemigrations` para que ele colete todas as alterações feita em seu projeto, por fim chame `python manage.py migrate` para que as mudanças sejam aplicadas no banco de dados. 
Nessa etapa, caso sua tabela não exista, o `migrate` se encarregará de cria-lo.

Para entender melhor do assunto de uma lida na documentação [inicial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/intro/).
Cito aqui um fragmento da fonte para que fique claro:

> O comando migrate verifica a configuração em INSTALLED_APPS e cria qualquer tabela do banco de dados necessária de acordo com as configurações do banco de dados no seu arquivo mysite/settings.py

Comment: ele retorna "No migrations to aply". E eu testei em um código funcional do Git de um amigo meu....

Comment: Nesse caso, provavelmente as tabelas ja foram criadas, você tem acesso ao banco ? Poderia atualizar sua pergunta com um exemplo de código ? fica mais fácil analisar

Comment: Antes de executar o camando **migrate**, você deve dar a conhecer sobre as modificações que fizeste no teu código, em termo de estrutura da base de dados. Para informar, você usa o comando **makemigrations**, sem executar antes esse comando, você pode alterar a estrutura e de seguida executar **migrate** e ele vai continuar a reportar _no migrations to apply_.